# Writing a cache provider with Redis and Service Stack for Piranha - keeping track of cached object type

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack.redis, piranha-cms

I'm writing a caching provider to cache any type of object.  The problem is casting to the correct type when I read the value out of the cache.

```
using (var redisClient = redisClientsManager.GetClient())
{
    redisClient.Set(key, value, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
}
```

So it's very easy to throw an object into cache where it gets converted to string.  When I come to pulling it out of the cache is where it gets interesting

```
 using (var redisClient = redisClientsManager.GetClient())
 {
     return redisClient.Get<object>(key);
 }
```

This does not work as we don't have the proper type to cast to so the default is to return the json string.

I'm thinking that I should maybe create a hash for all my piranha objects then having something like this

```
 piranha:cache id = "{ some json }"
 piranha:cache id:type = PAGETYPE
```

This would allow me to set the object type when I'm saving the object to cache.  I'm wondering if there's a better way to get/set the object type of what's being cached?

Ideally the code would do the casting explicitly however the caching in redis at the moment just uses the object type (I think).

---

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        using (var redisClient = redisClientsManager.GetClient())
        {
            if (redisClient.HashContainsEntry(PiranhaHash, key))
            {
                string resultJson = redisClient.GetValueFromHash(PiranhaHash, key);
                string objType = redisClient.GetValueFromHash(PiranhaHash, String.Format("{0}:Type", key));

                Type t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(objType);
                object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultJson, t);

                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        using (var redisClient = redisClientsManager.GetClient())
        {
            redisClient.SetEntryInHash(PiranhaHash, key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            redisClient.SetEntryInHash(PiranhaHash, String.Format("{0}:Type", key), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value.GetType()));
        }
    }
}
```

For the most part this implementation should work however the Page object won't deserialise from Json properly and the controller will always be null.  I think there will have to be some back end changes to make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of different cache-providers are currently quite limited, we could always change the provider interface for something that will work better in the long run. I've also had some thoughts about making the Get operations generic to clean up the code accessing the cache.

Maybe this interface would work better in the long run:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the cached model for the given key.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The model type</typeparam>
/// <param name="key">The unique key</param>
/// <returns>The model</returns>
T Get<T>(string key);

/// <summary>
/// Sets the cached model for the given key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The unique key</param>
/// <param name="obj">The model</param>
void Set(string key, object obj);

/// <summary>
/// Removes the cached model for the given key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The unique key</param>
void Remove(string key);
```

Since a change of this kind will result in a **lot** of updates in the core repository I have to implement it in a separate branch for testing which you could implement your provider with.

---

**EDIT**

I took a closer look at the Page object, and the fields `Controller, View, Redirect, IsPublished & IsStartpage` are calculated properties without a set accessor. This fields should not be serialized to JSON. Which serializer is being used and what attributes can be used to make the serializer ignore properties (like ScriptIgnore).

Furthermore the properties `TemplateController, TemplateView, TemplateRedirect & TemplateName` have private set accessors, I don't know if this will be a problem with the JSON-serializer being used.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Hi Hakan, I think this would be the best solution however I'm still not sure it would solve the problem here where the Page object can't be serialised/deserialised properly into json.

Comment: Hi, I tried both the service stack serialiser and the newtonsoft.  I'll try and create a pull request for you with my attempt tomorrow